# Windows 7 Pro losing LAN connectivity but wireless systems are having no problems

Tags: windows-7, windows-server-2012, hp-procurve

We have 50 Windows 7 Pro 32-bit desktops at one of our sites, connected to a Windows 2012 AD. They have all started losing network connectivity (connectivity to our main site over a metro-e network, randomly. The user can reboot several times and then it will reconnect for a undetermined amount of time and drop again.

The desktops, once they have lost connectivity, can ping to their gateway and other systems at that location. They can't ping the main site, which means they have no internet.

This location has seven Procurve layer 3 switches, one IDF that the Metro-E is connected to and feeds the MDF. The MDF feeds the other five switches. All switches have desktops connected to them, Cat6, and all have the same issue.

Any help will be greatly appreciated. I know this is a lot and could be a variety of issues but we have tried several things to no avail.

Comment: Please elaborate what exactly you mean by "losing network connectivity" in terms of actual specific technical symptoms, error messages etc., explain why "can't ping the main site" implies "they have no internet", and expand on the remark in your subject line about wireless systems having no problems which isn't taken up anywhere in the body of your question.

Comment: The systems suddenly cannot ping outside their internal network. They can ping their gateway switch and internal ips. This site connects, via metro-e, to our main site that hosts the AD and routes everything out to the cloud. The only error we get is the network logo gets a yellow triangle. Nothing in the event logs.

Comment: The desktops, with wireless NICs, and notebooks do not experience the issue. They do not lose network connectivity, so they do not lose internet either. Users can be on their desktop and notebook at the same time, and lose network on the desktop. The notebook will never lose connection.  The wireless APs are connected to the same switches that the desktops are connected to.

Comment: "Cannot ping" is much too vague. Please report actual commands you tried and results from these. But I'll venture a guess. Could it be that the affected clients are actually losing not connectivity, but the ability to resolve DNS names? Did you test for that?